# Assurance that a User is on the "Right" Web Page?

Tags: javascript, authentication, phishing

When you create a web application, how can you be sure a user is on your web page and not on a spoofed web page utilized in a MITM attack?

This simply stated problem seems incredibly difficult to solve.

Solutions like one time pass codes (OTP) through SMS or RSA are fallible if the user thinks he/she is on "www.chase.com" but is really on "www.chaze.com" (see the graphic below).

[image]

Any insight/help with this question will be greatly appreciated.

WebAuthn is NOT the answer.

Comment: You want to look up "CSRF"

Comment: A rock-solid way to do this is by using WebAuthn. Browsers simply don't allow you to log in on site B with credentials from site A. Other than that it really comes down to educating users, training them to watch the addressbar. Use google to reach the site instead of clicking links in emails, etc.

Comment: Modern, sophisticated applications are also a lot better these days in detecting unusual  traffic patterns for known account, but this isn't rock-solid.

Comment: use https with certificates (https://securebox.comodo.com/ssl-sniffing/man-in-the-middle-attack/)

Comment: The use of security keys in WebAuthn is problematic (both inconvenient for the user and insecure if the user leaves his/her key plugged in and walks away from his/her workstation).  Also, WebAuthn is not fully implemented; maybe when mobile authenticators over BLE are available (with a good API for developers) WebAuthn might be useful.  But for now, WebAuthn is NOT the answer.

Comment: Thx Mike.  "CSRF is an attack that tricks the [authenticated] victim into submitting a malicious request. It inherits the identity and privileges of the victim to perform an undesired function... For most sites, browser requests automatically include any credentials associated with the site... Therefore, if the user is currently authenticated to the site, the site will have no way to distinguish between the forged request sent by the victim and a legitimate request sent by the victim." 
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)
What about prior to log in?

Comment: Thx Claudia.  The information at the link is very informative, but primarily focused on public Wi-Fi hotspots.  I am specifically trying to solve the problem of a user who thinks he/she is on "www.chase.com" but is really on "www.chaze.com".  All the data from a fake website can be programatically relayed (by the server in the middle) and information can be sent to the user that makes everything appear legitimate.

Comment: Why do you think that's your problem to fix?